# Reading DATA from an OBJECT asp.net MVC C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, object, types

I am new to the MVC and I am stuck with a wierd situation. I have to read the Data from the type object and I tried different ways and I couldn't get a solution.Please help.

```
        IList<User> u = new UserRepository().Getuser(Name.ToUpper(), UserName.ToUpper(), UserCertNumber.ToUpper(), Date.ToUpper(), UserType.ToUpper(), Company.ToUpper(), PageNumber, Orderby, SearchALL.ToUpper(), PrintAllPages.ToUpper());


        object[] users = new object[u.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < u.Count; i++)
        {
            users[i] = new
            {
                Id = u[i].UserId,
                Title = u[i].Title,
                FirstName = u[i].FirstName,
                LastName = u[i].LastName,
                Privileges = (from apps in u[i].UserPrivileges select new { PrivilegeId = apps.Privilege.PrivilegeId, PrivilegeName = apps.Privilege.Name, DeactiveDate = apps.DeactiveDate }),
                Status = (from status in u[i].UserStatus select new { StatusId = status.Status.StatusId, StatusName = status.Status.StatusName, DeactiveDate = status.DeactiveDate }),
                ActiveDate = u[i].ActiveDate,
                UserName = u[i].Email,
                UserCN = (from cert in u[i].UserCertificates select new { CertificateNumber = cert.CertificateNumber, DeactiveDate = cert.DeactiveDate }),
                Company = u[i].Company.Name

            };
        }



        string x = "";
        string y = "";

        var report = users;


        foreach (var r in report)
        {
            x = r[0].....;
            i want to assign the values from the report to something else and I am not able to read the data from the report object. Please help.
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Select extension method so that you are directly creating the anonymous typed objects, rather than assigning them to a object of the generic Object class. You'll then be able to refer to the object's properties as desired.

```
   IList<User> us = new UserRepository().Getuser( Name.ToUpper(),
                                                  UserName.ToUpper(),
                                                  UserCertNumber.ToUpper(),
                                                  Date.ToUpper(),
                                                  UserType.ToUpper(),
                                                  Company.ToUpper(),
                                                  PageNumber,
                                                  Orderby,
                                                  SearchALL.ToUpper(),
                                                  PrintAllPages.ToUpper()); 

    var users = us.Select( u =>  new 
        { 
            Id = u[i].UserId, 
            Title = u[i].Title, 
            FirstName = u[i].FirstName, 
            LastName = u[i].LastName, 
            Privileges = (from apps in u[i].UserPrivileges select new { PrivilegeId = apps.Privilege.PrivilegeId, PrivilegeName = apps.Privilege.Name, DeactiveDate = apps.DeactiveDate }), 
            Status = (from status in u[i].UserStatus select new { StatusId = status.Status.StatusId, StatusName = status.Status.StatusName, DeactiveDate = status.DeactiveDate }), 
            ActiveDate = u[i].ActiveDate, 
            UserName = u[i].Email, 
            UserCN = (from cert in u[i].UserCertificates select new { CertificateNumber = cert.CertificateNumber, DeactiveDate = cert.DeactiveDate }), 
            Company = u[i].Company.Name 

        }); 


    string x = ""; 
    string y = ""; 

    var report = users; 

    foreach (var r in report) 
    { 
        var company = r.Company; // example
        ...
    }
```

**EDIT**: BTW, is there some reason why you are converting all those parameters to uppercase rather than simply doing case invariant comparisons in your repository?

Comment: My Friend You are AWESOME.AWESOME..and AWESOME. It worked like a champ on the first shot. Thanks a TON :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it, you create an anonymous type.

Create a class that contains those properties. Another way would be to put the report reading stuff inside the loop.

Comment: solution by tvanfosson worked for me. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
object o = new { Name = "string" };
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(o, null));
```

But this is not really recommended practise. I would create standard data transfer class for this purpose.

Comment: solution by tvanfosson worked for me. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding to tvanfosson solution :

If we want to get the PrivilegeName we do:

```
            foreach (var r in report) 
            { 
                x = r.FirstName; // example

                foreach (var s in r.Privileges)
                {
                    y = s.PrivilegeName; //Example
                }

            }
```